# Slow performance writing to S3

Tags: python-3.x, performance, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am currently writing a Glue Job using Apache Spark and writing to parquet in S3 is very slow (about 40 minutes). This is the code:

```
spark.conf.set("shark.sql.sourcess.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
my_df.repartition(10).write.partitionBy("some column").mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://..")
```

This results ins about 250 folders in the S3 path each containing 10 files with each being about 8MB in size.

Glue is configured with 20 workers and a Max capacity of 20 DPUs and an increase has not resulted in improvements.

Is it possible to optimize the performance?

Comment: what is the reason for repartition here?

Comment: and are you sure it's this that's taking longer and not earlier operations like any joins or group by?

Comment: There is a print before and after this statement with a difference of 40 minutes in between

Comment: @PiyushPatel Would it be faster without it?

Comment: I mean spark is lazily evaluated so just because there is no statement before it doesn't mean it is the one which is taking longer. I am now more inclined that it's not this statement but earlier statements which are causing such delay.

Comment: Thanks @PiyushPatel! I was not aware that the statements are executed lazily - then it is very likely that it is the explanation.